# Jquery UI Dual datepicker : On Hover highlight "from" to "range"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery datepicker on my page which shows 2 months.

It allows the user to select the `Send` and `Deliver` date which are (assume) **3 days** apart. When the user hovers over a `Send` date I need to highlight the dates between `Send` and `Deliver`. I need to the do the reverse too. i.e on hover of `Deliver` highlight days between `Deliver` and `Send`.

I tried googling for the same but the only results that I get are for the `beforeShowDay` which works only before showing the calendar.

Any help/links would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a demo using http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QKr5z/ : It only had the calendar.

Comment: So if the `Send` date is `5 Oct 2012` and Deliver date is `8 Oct 2012` then when over over `Send` label a tooltip with `6, 7 and 8 Oct 2012` has to be shown, is it correct?

Comment: Dint really understand the tooltip part, but the days 6,7 and 8 should be highlighted

Comment: What do u mean by highlighted?

Comment: A different background color or bold font etc

Comment: this one seems to have your desired behavior, but its based on Prototype: http://stephencelis.github.com/timeframe/#example_information